# importing style-sheet into app.scss to use throughout project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to use a style page across my app.

in the `app.scss` file I tried using:

```
@import "../global-scss/html-table-styles.scss";
```

this does not work.

Pasting the style directly into the `app.scss` file does work but I would rather not do that.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to my poor understanding of style-sheets and because there is an answer already so I am unable to delete.

In the style-sheet I was trying to import I had followed the pattern used for styles local to a page and had a base style tag

eg:

```
html-table-styles{
//my styles
}
```

when i imported `@import "../global-scss/html-table-styles.scss";` the styles were not being used, removing `html-table-styles` solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

If your file structure is like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── app
│   │   ├── app.component.ts
│   │   ├── app.module.ts
│   │   ├── app.scss
│   │   └── main.ts

// ... pages, components ...

|   └── theme
│       ├── custom-styles.scss
```

...the import line should be:

```
@import "../theme/custom-styles.scss";
```

Comment: Hi Ben, the path is correct. My project fails to build if the path is incorrect, maybe it is not the same for everyone

Comment: you set me on the right path though, I have a bad understanding of css and had a html-table-styles base for the scss instead of just havinh layouts